# Replace empty datetime value with other datetime value from same dataframe based on some condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe:

```
                  login   Status               start
0   2021-05-28 09:29:35 Resolved                 NaT
1   2021-05-28 11:46:11   Closed                 NaT
2   2021-05-29 15:59:16      WIP                 NaT
3   2021-05-30 10:43:57   Closed 2021-05-31 12:53:57
4   2021-06-27 17:53:29 Resolved                 NaT
```

I want to fill `start` value with `login` value if start is `NULL` and Status is either Resolved or Closed.
Expected DataFrame:

```
                  login   Status               start
0   2021-05-28 09:29:35 Resolved 2021-05-28 09:29:35
1   2021-05-28 11:46:11   Closed 2021-05-28 11:46:11
2   2021-05-29 15:59:16      WIP                 NaT
3   2021-05-30 10:43:57   Closed 2021-05-31 12:53:57
4   2021-06-27 17:53:29 Resolved 2021-06-27 17:53:29
```

iam unable to put condition for `Null` start values

I tried to make a function :

```
def fun(row):       
    if row.start.isna() and (row['Status'] == 'Resolved') or (row['Status' == 'Closed']):
        return row['start']
    else:
        return row['login']
```

and then using `apply` to run the function:

```
df['start'] = df.apply(fun, axis=1)
```

But iam getting error :

```
AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'isna'
```

How can we get the above result

TIA

Comment: Try using `.isnull()` rather than `.isna()`?

Comment: Same error > AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'isnull'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `fill` the `NaT` values in `start` after masking the values in `login` where the corresponding `Status` is not one of `Closed, Resolved`

```
m = df['Status'].isin(['Resolved', 'Closed'])
df['start'] = df['start'].fillna(df['login'].mask(~m))
```

---

```
  login                Status   start
0 2021-05-28 09:29:35  Resolved 2021-05-28 09:29:35
1 2021-05-28 11:46:11    Closed 2021-05-28 11:46:11
2 2021-05-29 15:59:16       WIP                 NaT
3 2021-05-30 10:43:57    Closed 2021-05-31 12:53:57
4 2021-06-27 17:53:29  Resolved 2021-06-27 17:53:29
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple `fillna()` with `.loc[]`

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""                  login   Status               start
0   2021-05-28 09:29:35  Resolved                 NaT
1   2021-05-28 11:46:11   Closed                 NaT
2   2021-05-29 15:59:16      WIP                 NaT
3   2021-05-30 10:43:57   Closed  2021-05-31 12:53:57
4   2021-06-27 17:53:29  Resolved                 NaT"""), sep="\s\s+", engine="python")
df["login"] = pd.to_datetime(df["login"])
df["start"] = pd.to_datetime(df["start"])

df.loc[~df["Status"].eq("WIP"),"start"] = df.loc[~df["Status"].eq("WIP"),"start"].fillna(df["login"])

df
```

|  | login | Status | start |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-05-28 09:29:35 | Resolved | 2021-05-28 09:29:35 |
| 1 | 2021-05-28 11:46:11 | Closed | 2021-05-28 11:46:11 |
| 2 | 2021-05-29 15:59:16 | WIP | NaT |
| 3 | 2021-05-30 10:43:57 | Closed | 2021-05-31 12:53:57 |
| 4 | 2021-06-27 17:53:29 | Resolved | 2021-06-27 17:53:29 |